# Version sorting RPM Kernel string with numbers in bash returns incorrect result

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I need the latest version out of these 4 kernel versions.

- 4.18.0-187.el8.x86_64
- 4.18.0-193.14.3.el8_2.x86_64
- 4.18.0-193.el8.x86_64
- 4.18.0-80.el8.x86_64

I had initially used numeric sort (which returns the 0-80 version incorrectly) before moving onto version sort for the same

```
latest_kernel_in_use=$(ls boot/vmlinuz* | sed 's/\/boot\/vmlinuz-//' | sort -V | tail -n1 )
```

The command still returns 4.18.0-193.el8.x86_64 versus the desired 4.18.0-193.14.3.el8_2.x86_64 output.

Help me out with the correction in the command.
I tested additionally and it's really the suffixes .el8.x86_64 complicating the sorting.

[Edit]
So I did it eventually, I removed the trailing alphabet/alphanumeric sequence, identifier being there is atleast one alphabet involved whether RPM kernel version is **4.18.0-193.14.3.el8_2.x86_64** or something like **4.18.0-193.14.3-generic** as seen in Ubuntu

```
latest_kernel_in_use=$(ls boot/vmlinuz* | sed 's/boot\/vmlinuz-//' | sed 's/[.-][[:alpha:]][[:alnum:][:punct:]]*//' | sort -V | tail -n1)
```

The Output with this is
4.18.0-193.14.3

I can work from there.

Comment: Since you are already  using `sed` to extracting  the versions, you could for instance use it for inserting a space in front of the `.e`, and then tell `sort` to sort on the first field only.

Comment: Comparing RPM version numbers is tricky.  See [How do I compare Rpm versions in python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3206319/4154375) for details of how to do it with Python.  If you must do it with Bash, the best option is to install the [rpmdevtools](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Rpmdevtools) package and use `rpmdev-vercmp`.

Comment: @user1934428
The problem is I won't be certain of the exact string which follows the version numbers. At times it's -generic (Ubuntu), or .el5/.el6 such as in the example shown here.

Comment: How then do you know where the version number ends?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I did it eventually, I removed the trailing alphabet/alphanumeric sequence, identifier being there is atleast one alphabet involved whether RPM kernel version is **4.18.0-193.14.3.el8_2.x86_64** or something like **4.18.0-193.14.3-generic** as seen in Ubuntu

```
latest_kernel_in_use=$(ls boot/vmlinuz* | sed 's/boot\/vmlinuz-//' | sed 's/[.-][[:alpha:]][[:alnum:][:punct:]]*//' | sort -V | tail -n1)
```

The Output with this is **4.18.0-193.14.3**

I can work from here.

Answer (score 0):

seems to be because "e" > 1

I came up with this horror but I am sure there is a better way

```
#!/bin/bash

# list your kernels and remove "vmlinuz-" prefix
KERNELS=$(find boot/ -iname "vmlinuz*" -exec basename {} \; | sed s/vmlinuz-//g)

# declare empty arrays (this will be arrays to contain our version and suffix strings)
VERSIONS_ARRAY=()
SUFFIXES_ARRAY=()

# we loop thought each kernel version
for KERNEL in $KERNELS;do
  # we will split each part of the kernel version on the dot (".")
  IFS="."
  read -ra KERNEL_VERSION <<< "$(echo $KERNEL)"
  # we define 2 empty strings to collect the kernel parts
  VERSION_STRING=""
  SUFFIX_STRING=""
  # we set back field separator to space
  IFS=" "
  # we loop throug all parts of kernel version
  for KERNEL_PART in ${KERNEL_VERSION[@]};do
    #echo -n $KERNEL_PART
    # if we encounter el8 or el8_2 or x86_64 string we append to the SUFFIX_STRING
    if [[ "$KERNEL_PART" == "el8" ]] || [[ "$KERNEL_PART" == "el8_2" ]] || [[ "$KERNEL_PART" == "x86_64" ]] ;then
      SUFFIX_STRING="${SUFFIX_STRING}${KERNEL_PART}."
    # else, we append to the VERSION_STRING
    else
      VERSION_STRING="${VERSION_STRING}${KERNEL_PART}."
    fi   
  done
  # we append the VERSION_STRING in VERSION_STRINGS
  VERSIONS_ARRAY+=("$VERSION_STRING")
  # we append the SUFFIX_STRING in SUFFIXES_ARRAYS
  SUFFIXES_ARRAY+=("$SUFFIX_STRING") 
done

# we set the field separator to split on linebreaks
IFS=$'\n'
# we find the highest value in version array
HIGHEST_VERSION=$(echo "${VERSIONS_ARRAY[*]}" | sort -V | tail -1)

# we get the position of highest value in array
for INDEX in ${VERSIONS_ARRAY[@]};do
    if [[ "$VERSIONS_ARRAY{[$INDEX]}" = "$HIGHEST_VERSION" ]]; then
        INDEX_OF_HIGHER_VERSION=$INDEX
    fi
done

# we get the corresponding suffix by index
HIGHEST_VERSION_SUFFIX=${SUFFIXES_ARRAY[$INDEX_OF_HIGHER_VERSION]}

# we remove the trailing dot in suffix
len=${#HIGHEST_VERSION_SUFFIX}
HIGHEST_VERSION_SUFFIX=${HIGHEST_VERSION_SUFFIX::len-1}

echo "vmlinuz-${HIGHEST_VERSION}${HIGHEST_VERSION_SUFFIX}"

# we set back field separator to space
IFS=" "
```

Answer (score 0):

latest_kernel_in_use=$(ls /boot/vmlinuz* | sed 's//boot/vmlinuz-//' | sed 's/[.-][[:alpha:]][[:alnum:][:punct:]]*//' | sort -V | tail -n1)

(/boot/vmlinux*) + s//boot ... )